# MATLAB: Set individual number of rows to zero without loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

In a matrix `mat` I would like to set an individual number of rows to zero according a cell array `startRows`that holds row numbers. I do have a working solution, however, I am wondering whether I can avoid the loop and replace it with some more sophisticated code?

```
mat = ones(100,5);
startRows = {10,10,30,10,40};

% How to avoid this loop?
for c = 1 : 5
    mat(1:startRows{c}-1, c) = 0;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Matlab's auto expansion of mismatched array sizes in recent versions. For older version of Matlab you will need to use [bsxfun](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) in the last line

```
mat = ones(100,5);
startRows = {10,10,30,10,40};
startRowsMatrix = [startRows{:}]

mat((1:100)' < [startRows{:}]) = 0;
```

Comment: This is great stuff. I didn't know about auto expansion. I stumbled upon the following blog, which explains the topic in more detail: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/